# Start Python program if it is not running

Tags: python-3.x

I have a Python3 program, `B.py` which I need to have run continuously. `B.py` may throw an exception and when that happens, I'd like to have it exit/shutdown. Pythong3 program `A.py` should watch and if `B.py` has exited, should start another instance of `B.py`.

I've searched SO and can't find a nice clean way. I'm not sure that writing the PID to a file is the best way to go (could the file be locked, for example?).

As a side note, I'm a python noobie, so please be as explicit as possible.

Answer (score 1):

The programs shown below are meant to demonstrate a very simple way of accomplishing your goal.

---

### A.py

The entire purpose of program **A** is to keep running program **B** over and over again. The `shell` argument is specified in this example so that it will easily run on both Windows and Linux, assuming program **B** has permission to execute. Feel free to expand on this program as you have need to.

```
#! /usr/bin/env python3
import subprocess


def main():
    while True:
        subprocess.run('B.py', shell=True)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

---

### B.py

This program should be replaced with your own, but it demonstrates a running program that crashes with random exceptions. The `EXCEPTIONS` strings is copied straight from the documentation, and the rest of the code should be easy to follow. The only use for this program is for testing program **A**.

```
#! /usr/bin/env python3
import builtins
import random
import time


EXCEPTIONS = '''\
BaseException
 +-- SystemExit
 +-- KeyboardInterrupt
 +-- GeneratorExit
 +-- Exception
      +-- StopIteration
      +-- StopAsyncIteration
      +-- ArithmeticError
      |    +-- FloatingPointError
      |    +-- OverflowError
      |    +-- ZeroDivisionError
      +-- AssertionError
      +-- AttributeError
      +-- BufferError
      +-- EOFError
      +-- ImportError
           +-- ModuleNotFoundError
      +-- LookupError
      |    +-- IndexError
      |    +-- KeyError
      +-- MemoryError
      +-- NameError
      |    +-- UnboundLocalError
      +-- OSError
      |    +-- BlockingIOError
      |    +-- ChildProcessError
      |    +-- ConnectionError
      |    |    +-- BrokenPipeError
      |    |    +-- ConnectionAbortedError
      |    |    +-- ConnectionRefusedError
      |    |    +-- ConnectionResetError
      |    +-- FileExistsError
      |    +-- FileNotFoundError
      |    +-- InterruptedError
      |    +-- IsADirectoryError
      |    +-- NotADirectoryError
      |    +-- PermissionError
      |    +-- ProcessLookupError
      |    +-- TimeoutError
      +-- ReferenceError
      +-- RuntimeError
      |    +-- NotImplementedError
      |    +-- RecursionError
      +-- SyntaxError
      |    +-- IndentationError
      |         +-- TabError
      +-- SystemError
      +-- TypeError
      +-- ValueError
      |    +-- UnicodeError
      |         +-- UnicodeDecodeError
      |         +-- UnicodeEncodeError
      |         +-- UnicodeTranslateError
      +-- Warning
           +-- DeprecationWarning
           +-- PendingDeprecationWarning
           +-- RuntimeWarning
           +-- SyntaxWarning
           +-- UserWarning
           +-- FutureWarning
           +-- ImportWarning
           +-- UnicodeWarning
           +-- BytesWarning
           +-- ResourceWarning
'''


def main():
    time.sleep(random.uniform(1, 9))
    lines = EXCEPTIONS.splitlines()
    names = [line.rsplit(None, 1)[-1] for line in lines]
    raise getattr(builtins, random.choice(names))()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```